# Pi 2 getting incredibly hot

Tags: gpio, pi-2

My raspberry pi 2 CPU is getting burning hot, even when just starting up. It first wouldn't display aswell, but I rewrote the 32 bit os onto the SD card and now it does display.
But it still is incredibly hot even though it works. I've been messing around with some wiring by getting power from the power supply by splitting the wires. But over removed all the wiring and it still keeps getting burning hot. Is there maybe a way to check if there is a short circuit somewhere on the board?

Comment: What is the actual temperature? In a terminal window enter 'vcgencmd measure_temp'

Comment: What is the ambient temperature? 76°C isn't necessarily too high ...

Answer (score 2):

If it gets hot when powered up with no SD card the Pi is in effect dead or dying.

Comment: are you absolutely sure? i really dont have the money to buy another one

Comment: What is the actual temperature? In a terminal window enter 'vcgencmd measure_temp'

Comment: It's 75.8 C, is that too High?

Comment: Not necessarily too high. That is below the temperature at which it will throttle (80C).

Comment: of course, it could be below 80C **because** it has throttled :p

Comment: Did you try to start the rpi **without the SD card** to test this?

Comment: I tested it but just by feel it seems to be the same temperature

Answer (score 0):

The *"terminal command"* [`vcgencmd` is your friend](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/os.html#vcgencmd).

"Just starting up" is the time when the RPi uses the most power. Let it run for 5 - 10 minutes, then open a terminal window and run `vcgencmd get_throttled`. [Refer to the documentation to interpret the results](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/os.html#get_throttled). Edit your question to add some specifics.